# Encoding problem when reading urls from a csv file in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, python-requests, lxml

I have a csv file with some urls; after reading through it, in python with:

```
import csv
rows = []
with open("links.csv","r", encoding = "utf-8") as c:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(c)
    for row in csv_reader:
        rows.append(row)
```

It returns a list with all the urls this csv file contains.
Then, I try to get an element via its XPATH route with "requests" and "lxml"

```
import requests
import lxml.html as html
def scraper():
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        try:
            article = requests.get(rows[i][0]) 
            if article.status_code == 200:
                artc = article.content.decode("utf-8")
                parsed = html.fromstring(artc)
                img_url = parsed.xpath(URL_1)
                img_url.append(img_links)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Error: {article.status_code!r}")
        except ValueError as ve:
            print(ve)
```

Now the problem is, when I run this program, the following error appears:

> No connection adapters were found for '\ufeffhttps://detail.1688.com/offer/524898885299.html?spm=a26352.b28411319.offerlist.290.ad1b1e625GXj5E'
> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte: invalid start byte

As a note: All these links are from chinese web pages such as 1688 or taobao which makes me think the problem has something to do with encoding. I've tried using "utf-8-sig". This solves the --'\ufeff problem-- but does not solve the --can't decode byte--

Comment: What line exactly does raise the error? Said differently, could you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: If the response cannot be decoded as UTF-8, then it's not UTF-8, which is not entirely surprising for Chinese websites. Have you checked what encoding they use and tried that instead?

Comment: There are two separate things happening here.
(1) you're now correctly removing the UTF8 BOM by using "utf-8-sig" - great
(2) in 'article.content.decode("utf-8")' you are making the assumption that the page is using UTF-8 encoding, which is not necessarily true.  You may have been intercepted by some intermediate captcha page that is not using UTF-8, etc.  You will need to inspect the article.content and try to determine the character set, possibly using chardet or equivalent.